# MONGO- weekly average distance for a given user Id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection  of

```
{ 
   id
   distance
   time
   date
   userId
}
```

I would like to get the weekly average distance for a given userId.
So far I managed to have

```
    Model.aggregate([{ 
                $project : {      
                        year : {
                            $year : "$date"
                        }, 

                        week : {
                            $week : "$date"
                        }    
                }
                }, {
                $group : {
                _id : {
                    year : "$year",
                    week : "$week"
                }
                total : {
                    $sum: 1
                } 
        }


} ]
```

And my output is the number of register that I have in my db per week but I coudn´t manage to go any further than that

I really appreciate any suggestion or help

Thanks in advace

Comment: can you add one sample data and expected output?

Comment: Something like `Model.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "year": {
          "$year": "$date"
        },
        "week": {
          "$week": "$date"
        }
      },
      "avgDistance": {
        "$avg": "$distance"
      }
    }
  }
])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to everybody,
At the end this worked for me

```
 Model.aggregate([
            {   $match: { userId:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }},
            {   $project : {      
                    year : { $year : "$date" }, 
                    week : { $week : "$date" },
                    userId: "$userId",
                    distance: "$distance",
                }
            },
            {   $group : {
                    _id : {
                        year : "$year",                      
                        week : "$week"
                    },             
                    distance:{ $avg: "$distance" },     
                    total : { $sum: 1 } 
                }
            }]
```

So the first match to get just the rows for our userId ( notice that the id has to ve a mongoose Object id, not a string or number ).

Then we use year and week as an id to avoid have same week for diferent years and finally we can get the average with $avg